# Как правильно записать словосочетание "рoбoт Mайтрейд" для программы?

Tags: грамматика, прописная-строчная, кавычки

Вопрос по такому предложению:

"***Как рoбoт-Mайтрейд оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда?***"

Пояснения:

1. **Mайтрейд** - это моё прозвище в трейдерской среде (пошло от моего **my-trade**.livejournal), а впоследствии и псевдоним.
2. **Роботами** трейдеры называют такие самописные программы, которые автоматически совершают сделки на биржевых рынках по определённым трейдерами алгоритмам.

Из википедии: В информационных технологиях «роботами» также называют некоторые автономно действующие программы, например, боты или поисковые роботы.

3. Под фразой "**рoбoт-Mайтрейд**" подразумевается программа, которая в точности повторяет то, как торгую я сам. Т.е. это будто копия меня на бирже. Так же можно было бы назвать какую-нибудь нейросеть, которая общается в чатах в точности как я.

Т. к. я профан в русском языке, у меня возникает масса вопросов, как правильно писать:

- рoбoт-Mайтрейд
- рoбoт "Mайтрейд"
- рoбoт Mайтрейд
- рoбoт-"Mайтрейд"
- "рoбoт-Mайтрейд"

и т. д.

**UPDATE:** что я вынес для себя из всего прочитанного в ответах ниже и дискуссиях под ними?

- Вариант **робот-Mайтрейд** неправильный, но я в недоумении, почему в ПАС § 120 может быть программа-максимум, программа-минимум, а программа-Mайтрейд или программа-Гитлер быть не может? Такой удобный инструмент присвоения характеристики предмету отпадает :(
- Вариант **роботMайтрейд/робоMайтрейд** неправильный из-за большой буквы в середине слова. Хотя, как подметил Александр Стрелец:"...орфографическая норма в последнее время все чаще игнорируется" СберМаркет, ВкусВилл, ВКонтакте, КонсультантПлюс, МегаФон".
- Вариант **робот Mайтрейд** (или **робот "Mайтрейд"**) правильный, но подходит по смыслу не так хорошо как мог бы робот-Mайтрейд, потому что от Mайтрейда носит только название. Т.е. здесь робот+название робота, но присвоение роботу характеристик самого Mайтрейда здесь нет(что он торгует КАК\СЛОВНО\БУДТО\В ТОЧНОСТИ КАК Mайтрейд), в лучшем случае только намёк. По той же логике для меня пользователь "Дурачок" звучит не так безысходно, как пользователь-дурачок.
- Вариант **Mайтрейд-робот** правильный, но он у меня вызывает вопросы. Иванушка-дурачок/Архип-кузнец/Маша-резвушка - все эти варианты вторым словом имеют приложение-характеристику, а не сам собственно объект о котором ведётся речь. Поэтому Mайтрейд-робот по этой конструкции означает, что я - робот. Хотя если написать Иванушка-клон, то вроде бы понятно, что речь идёт про клон, поэтому возможно из-за того, что Mайтрейд не может быть роботом, вариант Mайтрейд-робот может быть всё таки понят правильно, что речь о роботе, который работает в качестве Mайтрейда, а не Mайтрейд в качестве робота. Вариант **Майтрейд(робот)** аналогичен.
- Вариант **робот Mайтрейда** (родительный падеж). По смыслу ещё хуже, чем робот "Майтрейд", потому что он тоже может быть каким-угодно, абсолютно не таким как Майтрейд (робот-пылесос, например), тем более что их может быть много (роботов у Майтрейда).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151260/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

*Как **Майтрейд-робот** оказался лучше самого ***Майтрейда***?*

**Пояснение**

1. Некорректно написание **через дефис** (строчная и прописная буквы): ***робот-Майтрейд.***
2. Вариант ***робот Майтрейд*** —  это приложение + название. Но это ваше имя, а не имя робота.
3. Вариант ***робот "Майтрейд"*** — это тоже приложение + название, то есть робот будет называться "Майтрейд". Это уже не вы, но в названии **нет информации** о том, что это робот (только кавычки, а их недостаточно).
4. Дефисное написание ***Майтрейд-робот*** вводит нарицательное слово в название, поэтому я предлагаю этот вариант.

**Примечание**. В нейросетях можно назваться  ***Робот Майтрейд***. Это будет имя собственное. Или дефисное написание слов с прописной буквы в любой последовательности.

Вопрос **дискуссионный**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (по комментарию)**

Правильное название кода: ***Робот Майтрейд.***

1. Если вы считаете, что это **уникальный самописный** код, то это **составное** имя собственное, оба слова пишутся с **прописной** буквы. Первое слово в любом случае пишут с прописной, а второе слово тоже имя.

**Кавычки** тогда не нужны. Вариант подходит как для торговли на бирже, так и для нейросетей.

3. **Робот** — это не вы, но робот может быть нарицательным словом (строчная буква), а может входить  в имя собственное (прописная буква). И если вы напишете: ***робот Майтрейд,*** то будете роботом).

**P. S.** Во всех ваших вариантах была **строчная** буква, поэтому **я считала**,что это **приложение** перед названием, а не само название. Другими словами, я думала, что робот — это программа с алгоритмом действий, нарицательное существительное.

Но если код уникальный, то слово "робот" входит в название и пишется **с прописной.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151218/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Обсуждение темы по вопросу: "Как робот-Майтрейд оказался лучше самого Майтрейда?"

```
Вы вместе много всего здесь написали, о всяких сущностях. 
Для себя я понял следующее. Есть человек Лёха. Одна из его 
"ролей" – трейдер по имени/прозвищу Майтрейд. Он (Лёха, Майтрейд, 
Лёха-Майтрейд – неважно) создал робота, который может его 
заменять на этом "узком" поприще. Их функции неотличимы. Работать 
может и Майтрейд-человек, и Майтрейд-робот. Поэтому, думаю, самый 
верный вариант для заданного предложения такой:
Как робот Майтрейд оказался лучше самого Майтрейда. // Кавычки 
вообще не нужны, зачем нагромождать?  У специалиста-трейдера и 
программы-робота одно имя. – Александр Стрелец
```

1. Спасибо за  ответ. Я говорила о сторонах личности, а вы говорите о  **функциях**, которые неотличимы. Это примерно одно и то же, только **без философии** с уклоном в психологию.
2. Кстати, здесь возможны **два варианта** прочтения:

(1) ***Как** (каким образом?) **робот Майтрейд** оказался лучше самого Майтрейда?* Рассказ о самой программе.  Возможно: ***Майтрейд-робот.***

(2) ***Как робот** (в качестве робота) Майтрейд оказался лучше самого Майтрейда?*  Робот очень хорош! Рассказ об успешном применении программы.

Все зависит от **содержания** статьи. Поэтому останавливаемся на варианте:
*Как **робот Майтрейд** оказался лучше самого Майтрейда?*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Посмотрела **названия торговых роботов** и др.  Почти все на латинице, причем в свободном режиме, например:

***RoboForex*** — брокерская компания.

Торговоый робот ***"Jerold".***

Робот искусственного интеллекта **JEROLD (Джеральд)**.

Лучший торговый робот ***Forex Setka Trader***.

***«Золотой Жук 4.0»*** — торговый робот для торговли золотом.

Торговая платформа ***MetaTrader 4/5.***

Это в качестве  **примеров**, если захотите **назвать** программу.

В качестве примера: торговый робот ***"My-trade"***  (можно без кавычек). Но в предложении это делать необязательно, если названия еще нет. Там можно использовать нарицательное сочетание ***робот Майтрейда*** (= разработанный Майтрейдом).

Другие варианты — это уже **названия**))  Вы называете робота своим именем: то есть он **робот Майтрейд** (или **Майтрейд-робот**), а вы человек, которого называют Майтрейд в трейдерской среде. Вы с ним тёзки.

То есть вас **двое**:  Майтрейд-робот и Майтрейд-трейдер (= это вы).

Вот такое у меня **решение это задачи.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151277/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----oo-m); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

**Правило нужно?**

Вообще говоря,  дефисное написание ***робот-Майтрейд***  (строчная, потом прописная) нехарактерно для русского языка **вообще**.  Но можно правила найти и по **конкретной** теме.

Но с правилами здесь сложно,  **путеводитель нужен**)  Что-то есть  в ПАС под ред. Лопатина, а что-то у Розенталя (правда, в разделе пунктуация).  Лопатин только ***матушка-Русь*** разрешает так писать.

**[ПАС: § 120 и § 122](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65)**

Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных пишутся **через дефис**.

б) сочетания с однословными приложениями, **следующими** за определяемым словом, напр.: баба-яга, ванька-встанька, город-герой, ковёр-самолёт,  (устойчивые сочетания); дом-новостройка, журналист-между- народник, писатель-эмигрант, студент-медик, собака-ищейка,девочка-красавица, **Маша-резвушка** (свободные сочетания);

в) сочетания с однословными **приложениями, предшествующими** определяемому слову, напр.: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, трудяга-следователь, профан-редактор, пройдоха-управляющий. Такие приложения носят **оценочный** характер.

Сочетания этого типа с **собственными именами** обычно пишутся **раздельно**: старик Державин (П.), крошка Цахес (персонаж одноименной повести Гофмана), простак Ваня и т. п.; **но: матушка-Русь (Некр.).**

**[Розенталь, пункт 2, примечание 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)**

После собственного имени лица **дефис** ставится только в случае слияния определяемого существительного и приложения в одно сложное **интонационно-смысловое целое**: Иван-царевич, Иванушка-дурачок, Аника-воин, Дюма-отец, Рокфеллер-старший (но: **Катон Старший** — прозвище исторического лица).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151219/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Переношу последние комментарии из чата. Sharon пишет: "Александр, а как вам вариант роботМайтрейд? Он вне правил? Можно ли так вообще написать, как смотрится? А что бы вы выбрали? А то мне нужна моральная поддержка. Мой вариант: Майтрейд-робот".

Comment: Не, мне не нра. // Вы вместе много всего здесь написали, о всяких сущностях. Для себя я понял следующее. Есть человек Лёха. Одна из его "ролей" – трейдер по имени/прозвищу Майтрейд. Он (Лёха, Майтрейд, Лёха-Майтрейд – неважно) создал робота, который может его заменять на этом "узком" поприще. Их функции неотличимы. Работать может и Майтрейд-человек, и Майтрейд-робот. Поэтому, думаю, самый верный вариант для заданного предложения такой: ***Как робот Майтрейд оказался лучше самого Майтрейда***. // Кавычки вообще не нужны, зачем нагромождать? У специалиста-трейдера и программы-робота одно имя.

Comment: Нашёл вот такую цитату: "My_Trade не человек, это явление. Эгрегор рыночной ботвы". :)))

Comment: Нашла вот такую цитату: Звезда только одна - Лёша Майтрейд! Остальные так.. подзвёздыши)   // Больше похоже на правду.  Лидеры в любой области не нравятся  людям.

Comment: Да, тоже видел, хотел написать – *подзвёздыши* понравились! :)

Comment: Можно и робот Майнтред и робот-Майнтред. Остальное — у Шарон.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Можно так: робот-Майнтрейд?  Есть ссылка на вариант?

Comment: Уже по-немецки пишем? :) Май**н**трейд. Та не знаю я, вроде как нет. Утомили меня сущности ваши :))

Comment: Смешно-с.  Но весело было, Леха никак не хотел становиться роботом, как я его ни уговаривала.

Comment: @Sharon Ну как я могу быть роботом, если он на отдельной флешке хранится. Можете привести пример, где вы - это что-то отдельное от себя?)) Я хоть буду знать, как вы это понимаете. Вот вы приготовили котлеты сегодня. Вы что, котлеты?) Наверное же, вы тоже не хотите становиться котлетами, как вас не уговаривай)). У ваших котлет задача быть съедеными вами. А у моего робота задача торговать как я. Это разве что-то меняет? Торговать то робот будет, а не я. Мне мутировать в робота не нужно для этого в полнолуние))) Как оборотень в фильмах ужасов)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец "Уже по-немецки пишем? :)" - кстати я слышал, что вопросительные и восклицательные знаки ставятся после смайла, а не до :)

Comment: @ЛёхаМайтрейд Не встречал никаких рекомендаций насчет смайлов. По-моему, их использование нигде пока не регламентировано. Мне кажется, некрасиво будет, если поставить смайл перед ? (или ! / или ...) Оторванность какая-то получится. Сначала, думаю, должна быть мысль (правильная пунктуация и синтаксис), а потом реакция-эмоция на нее в виде смайла.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  Артемий Лебедев «Ководство». Грамота на него ссылается также.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Скажите, а вы тексты за отдельную плату не проверяете? Если да, сколько у вас будет стоит за каждую 1000 символов без пробелов?

Comment: @ЛёхаМайтрейд Спасибо, посмотрел, у него много чего интересного! Но по поводу смайликов я с ним не согласен :) Хотя вот точку мне тоже не хочется ставить не до не после. // Насчет коррекции. Да, я занимаюсь этим не на постоянной основе, даже написал вам вчера в Телеграм, но сегодня стёр, какие-то сомнения появились. Вы говорили, что тексты сложные. Хотелось бы узнать, насколько сложные.

Comment: @ЛёхаМайтрейд, по аналогии с устройствами сочетаниями можно написать: робот-Майнтред. Если считать, что это название программы. И раздельно, если это название робота(бота).

Comment: @Серж, приведите пример и дайте ссылку на правило, пжста.

Comment: @Sharon, так вы же привели правила.

Comment: *устойчивыми сочетаниями хотел написать.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю еще один вариант **без союза** ***КАК***:

***Mайтрейд-робот** оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда.*

Или: ***Робот Mайтрейд** оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда.*

**Пояснение**

1. Вот автор объясняет *принцип работы* программы:

*Я сел за компьютер... торговал как обычно (как Майтрейд) и просадил 1000$. Потом запустил робота, который продолжил делать вместо меня то же самое и ушёл... В итоге робот просадил 900$.*

2. Союз ***КАК*** **затемняет** смысл сказанного. Возможны два толкования: вопросительное слово ***КАК*** (= каким образом) и союз ***КАК*** в сочетании "как робот" (= в качестве робота). А **смысловой** нагрузки у слова ***КАК*** нет, предложение  без союза имеет тот же смысл.
3. Вариант ***Майтрейд-робот*** представляется программой вполне самостоятельной: пользователь запустил ее и ушел. Поэтому программа имеет право на собственное имя ***Майтрейд-робот***.
4. При другом нарицательном существительном в качестве приложения можно записать так: *Программа ***"Майтрейд-робот"*** работает лучше самого Майтрейда.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151255/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----oo-m); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.