# Какие трудности возможны при выборе названия компьютерной программы?

Tags: грамматика, ономастика, приложение, имена-нарицательные

Вопрос задан по теме   **[Как правильно записать словосочетание "рoбoт Mайтрейд" для программы?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478715/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80o%D0%B1o%D1%82-m%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)**

При обсуждении встал вопрос о правильной **семантике и грамматике** названий. Какой грамматический материал необходимо знать **для решения** этой задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тема, на которую вы ссылаетесь в этом вопросе, немного сложнее, чем её название. Там скорее "Как правильно записать словосочетание "рoбoт Mайтрейд" для программы так, чтобы дать понять, что она копирует\имитирует\заменяет Майтрейда?"

Моя тема — не редкий уникальный случай, думаю, что это распространённый запрос, потому что вы сами же приводите определение:

> "*РОБОТ, -а; м. [чешск. robot]. Автоматизированное устройство,
> **предназначенное для замены человека** при выполнении монотонных или опасных работ.*"

Т. е. факт того, что робот заменяет\подменяет\имитирует\пародирует\копирует и т. д. и т. п. — в этом нет ничего удивительного, ведь роботы для этого часто и предназначены. Особенно нейросети.

В вашем ответе на свой вопрос отличная кодификация правил русского языка по теме "как писать название", но не решает задачу "как писать название так, чтобы это указывало на факт имитации роботом (программой) действий человека".

Все ваши итоговые варианты на это не указывают явно:

- **робот Майтрейда** может быть роботом-пылесосом в его квартире;
- **робот Майтрейд** или **робот "Майтрейд"**, а также **Майтрейд-робот** можно воспринять так, будто это сам Майтрейд имитирует робота, например, в качестве метафоры.

Поэтому, отвечая на вопрос: "Какой грамматический материал необходимо знать для решения этой задачи?", нужно рассмотреть, например, вариант со скобками: "*Каким образом **робот (как Майтрейд)** оказался лучше Майтрейда?*"

Т. е. хотелось бы дополнить эту тему правилами о скобках и чем они отличаются от дефиса, если эти различия есть. Тему дефиса вы раскрыли, но у дефиса есть проблемы: после него не запишешь несколько слов и не запишешь имён собственных. Скобки, надеюсь, таких ограничений лишены, поэтому достойны рассмотрения.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151340/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

О грамматике и семантике **нарицательных и собственных имен**

**ВВЕДЕНИЕ В ТЕМУ**

**Раздельное и дефисное написание приложений** (грамматика, смысл, произношение)

1. **Приложение – это определение,** выраженное существительным, соответственно, связь между двумя существительными является **подчинительной**. Нормальной позицией для приложения является позиция перед определяемым словом (раздельное написание), а при инверсии приложение стоит после определяемого слова (тогда оно всегда пишется через дефис). Например: ***гора Казбек*** и ***Казбек-гора***.
2. **О дефисной форме письма**

Самым общим значением дефисной формы является отражение на письме **смыслового ЕДИНСТВА слов**. Например, через дефис пишутся существительные с **сочинительной** связью основ: *вопросы-ответы, хлеб-соль, друзья-приятели*. Если в сложном слове появляется оттенок **подчинения**, то основное существительное всегда пишется **на первом** месте, а менее значимое – на втором: ***диван-кровать, музей-квартира***.

3. **Произношение**

Интересно то, что  форма написания отражается на произношении слов.  **Словосочетание** произносится с паузой, интонационное ударение уходит на конец словосочетания:  ***кузнец АрхИп***. Слово с дефисным написанием произносится слитно (без паузы), но там два ударения: ***АрхИп-кузнЕц***. На главном слове (Архип) делается основное ударение, а на приложении – вспомогательное ударение.

**ДВЕ СМЫСЛОВЫЕ ГРУППЫ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ**

1. **Качественная оценка**

В качестве приложения могут выступать существительные со следующими значениями:

1. значение **качества или свойства**: *поэт-новатор, механик-самоучка*;
2. эмоциональная **оценка** или поэтическое **сравнение**: *горе-охотник, старушка-золото; утес-великан, сапоги-скороходы*.

2. **Различные отношения**

**Тематические группы приложений:**

1. сочетание **профессии, степени родства, национальности**:
   *брат-учитель, возница-киргиз, старик-крестьянин, студен-заочник* (приложение на втором месте);
2. **нарицательные и собственные существительные**: *девочка Женя, город Москва, река Волга, газета «Труд», учитель Иванов, кузнец Архип, писатель Толстой, игра Minecraft, робот-игрушка «Черный Дракон»*;
3. **родовое и видовое** наименование: *птица соловей, трава подорожник*.

**ВЫБИРАЕМ НАЗВАНИЕ ДЛЯ ПРОГРАММЫ**

1. Это робот, созданный **Майтрейдом**. Пока у него нет названия, мы можем сказать, что это ***робот Майтрейда*** (Р. п). Родительный падеж обозначает принадлежность данной программы автору Майтрейду.
2. Но программе обычно дают имя. Попробуем назвать его тоже **Майтрейд**, теперь это имя собственное: **робот** (по имени)  **Майтрейд**.
3. Дефисная форма тоже возможна, смысл не меняется: ***Майтрейд-робот***. А точно ли не меняется? Нет, не меняется, **оценочного** значения здесь по-прежнему нет. Но вот **что плохо**: сочетание можно понять иначе: ***Майтрейд-робот*** — это **сам автор**, в чем-то похожий на робота. А вот это уже **оценочное** значение.

**РОБОТ**, -а; м. [чешск. robot]. Автоматизированное устройство, предназначенное для замены человека при выполнении монотонных или опасных работ. *Радиоуправляемый р. Работал как р.* / **Разг. О человеке**, действующем бессознательно, подчиняясь чужой воле. *Превратиться в робота. Это же р., а не человек.* Термин впервые употреблён К. Чапеком в пьесе "R.U.R." (1920).

4. Нет, уж лучше не называться **одним именем** с роботом, хотя бы **кавычки** надо добавить. Пусть он будет ***робот «Майтрейд»,   «Майтрейд»-робот***. Или можно дать название на латинице: ***робот My-trade***. Тогда будет удобно обозначать **модификации** основной модели.
5. Рассмотрим для сравнения **нарицательные** существительные вида ***«робот-пылесос»***. Какие здесь отношения? Это **родо-видовые** отношения. На первом месте основное существительное ***робот*** со значением рода (автоматизированное устройство), а на втором месте сущ. ***пылесос*** со значением вида (автоматизированный бытовой прибор для удаления пыли).

Здесь **нет собственных** имен: пылесос – это не название робота, а его **видовая** характеристика. А вот считать сочетание ***робот Майтрейд*** нарицательным мы никак не можем. Между этими вариантами **принципиальная** разница.

**ВЫВОД**

Если нет названия, то пишем: ***робот Майтрейда***. Если есть название: *робот Майтрейд, Майтрейд-робот, робот «Майтрейд», робот My-trade.*

Предложение при **отсутствии** названия: *Рoбoт **Mайтрейда** оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда.*

Предложение с названием: *Рoбoт **Mайтрейд** оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда.* И **другие** (названные выше и прочие) варианты названий.

Comment: Ну если это целое название программы почему не написать через дефис? Род. пад..указывает на принадлежность. Зачем он здесь? У нас ведь название программы.

Comment: (1) Название автор дает любое, но в данном случае он не хотел нарушать существующие орфографические нормы. (2) Речь шла о предложении, а робот не имел названия. Автор пока не планировал давать ему  имя.

Comment: Да, но ведь автор ведь пишет: "рoбoт-Mайтрейд" подразумевается программа, которая в точности повторяет то, как торгую я сам".

Comment: Он пишет  и спрашивает о правильности  такого написания. А вы говорите, что это правильно. А правило где?  //  И если у робота нет названия, то как вы запишете предложение? У вас есть  варианты?

Comment: Но и раздельное написание тоже не отрицаю. Какой вариант сформируется, покажет время.

Comment: Программа, которая в точности повторяет его действия. Т.е. оценочное название.Верно?

Comment: Я вас не понимаю.  Как записать предложение?

Comment: Оценочное? И это вы называете оценкой? Для чего и для кого я пишу грамматический материал из Грамматики-80?  (10 Значение качества или свойства: поэт-новатор, механик-самоучка. (2) горе-охотник, старушка-золото; утес-великан, сапоги-скороходы. Эмоциональная оценка или поэтическое сравнение:

Comment: Вы же сами пишете об оценочном значении в пункте 3. Верно? Только Майнтред на первом месте. Это сочетания типа старик отец. В ПАСе  такие названия тоже могут писаться через дефис.

Comment: Робот - как Майтрейд. Это сравнение? Тогда получится робот-Майтрейд. А это запрещенная форма.

Comment: Матйрейд-робот?  Пишите! Будет такое единое сочетание. А как отличить от Майтрейда-робота, который к автору относится: Майтрейд, превратившийся в робота.  Майтрейд-робот  можно было сразу написать и без сравнения.  Да и сравнения разные бывают.

Comment: Люди удивительные создания. Есть прямая и ясная дорога, но им хочется идти через непроходимый лес.

Comment: Прочитал наконец-то... Р. падеж хужее... // За, как всегда, отзывчивость к теме и новым участникам – большие плюсы!

Comment: Нет, хужее вашего утвержденного не сыщешь. Как рoбoт Mайтрейд оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда.  Перестановка: Mайтрейд как робот оказался лучше самого Mайтрейда.  Значение в качестве в обоих случаях. Вы же такой выбрали. А он Лехе во второй записи не нравится. И этот союз КАК, у него же два значения, запятую надо ставить, чтобы различить.

Comment: Я уже ничё не понямайю щас исправлю ваш ответ...